# numpy.where : how to delay evaluating parameters?

Tags: python, numpy, divide-by-zero

I am using `numpy.where`, and I was wondering if there was a simply way to avoid calling the unused parameter. Example:

```
import numpy as np
z = np.array([-2, -1, 0, 1, -2])
np.where(z!=0, 1/z, 1)
```

returns:

```
array([-0.5, -1. ,  1. ,  1. , -0.5])
```

but I get a divide by zero warning because when `z` was 0, the code still evaluates `1/z` even though it doesn't use it.

Comment: why don't you use z = z[np.nonzero(z)] then divide by z, but that just returns 1 so I guess I am not sure why

Comment: `1/z` is executed by the interpreter as part of calling `where`. That's not under the control of `where`. But you can do `out[ind]=1/z[ind]` where `ind` is the mask of ok values.  There are other ways of dealing divide by zero.

Comment: Search for the [numpy] and [divide-by-zero] tags

Answer (score 2):

You can also turn off the warning and turn it back on after you are done
using the context manager [`errstate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.errstate.html#numpy.errstate):

```
with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
    np.where(z!=0, 1/z, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a mask:

```
out = numpy.ones_like(z)
mask = z != 0
out[mask] = 1/z[mask]
```

Answer (score 0):

scipy has a little utility just for this purpose:
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/_lib/_util.py#L26

It's basically a matter of allocating the output array and using `np.place` (or putmask) to fill exactly what you need.