# Understanding the runtime of numpy.where and equivalent alternatives

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

According to http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html, if x and y are given and input arrays are 1-D, where is equivalent to `[xv if c else yv for (c,xv, yv) in zip(x!=0, 1/x, x)]`. When doing runtime benchmarks, however, they have significantly different speeds:

```
x = np.array(range(-500, 500))

%timeit np.where(x != 0, 1/x, x)
10000 loops, best of 3: 23.9 µs per loop

%timeit [xv if c else yv for (c,xv, yv) in zip(x!=0, 1/x, x)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 232 µs per loop
```

Is there a way I can rewrite the second form so that it has a similar runtime to the first? The reason I ask is because I'd like to use a slightly modified version of the second case to avoid division by zero errors:

```
[1 / xv if c else xv for (c,xv) in zip(x!=0, x)]
```

Another question: the first case returns a numpy array while the second case returns a list. Is the most efficient way to have the second case return an array is to first make a list and then convert the list to an array?

```
np.array([xv if c else yv for (c,xv, yv) in zip(x!=0, 1/x, x)])
```

Thanks!

Comment: numpy often does performance critical parts in wrapped C-code

Answer (score 3):

You just asked about 'delaying' the 'where':

[numpy.where : how to delay evaluating parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276813/numpy-where-how-to-delay-evaluating-parameters)

and someone else just asked about divide by zero:

[Replace all elements of a matrix by their inverses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38308945/replace-all-elements-of-a-matrix-by-their-inverses)

When people say that `where` is similar to the list comprehension, they attempt to describe the action, not the actual implementation.

`np.where` called with just one argument is the same as `np.nonzero`.  This quickly (in compiled code) loops through the argument, and collects the indices of all non-zero values.

`np.where` when called with 3 arguments, returns a new array, collecting values from the 2 and 3rd arguments based on the `nonzero` values.  But it's important to realize that those arguments must be other arrays.  They are not functions that it evaluates element by element.

So the `where` is more like:

```
m1 = 1/xv
m2 = xv
[v1 if c else v2 for (c, v1, v2) in zip(x!=0, m1, m2)]
```

It's easy to run this iteration in compiled code because it just involves 3 arrays of matching size (matching via broadcasting).

`np.array([...])` is a reasonable way of converting a list (or list comprehension) into an array.  It may be a little slower than some alternatives because `np.array` is a powerful general purpose function.  `np.fromiter([], dtype)` may be faster in some cases, because it isn't as general (you have to specify dtype, and it it only works with 1d).

There are 2 time proven strategies for getting more speed in element-by-element calculations:

- use packages like `numba` and `cython` to rewrite the problem as c code
- rework your calculations to use existing `numpy` methods.  The use of masking to avoid divide by zero is a good example of this.

=====================

`np.ma.where`, the version for masked arrays is written in Python.  Its code might be instructive.  Note in particular this piece:

```
# Construct an empty array and fill it
d = np.empty(fc.shape, dtype=ndtype).view(MaskedArray)
np.copyto(d._data, xv.astype(ndtype), where=fc)
np.copyto(d._data, yv.astype(ndtype), where=notfc)
```

It makes a target, and then selectively copies values from the 2 inputs arrays, based on the condition array.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid division by zero while maintaining performance by using advanced indexing:

```
x = np.arange(-500, 500)

result = np.empty(x.shape, dtype=float) # set the dtype to whatever is appropriate
nonzero = x != 0
result[nonzero] = 1/x[nonzero]
result[~nonzero] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you for some reason want to bypass an error with `numpy` it might be worth looking into the `errstate` context:

```
x  = np.array(range(-500, 500))

with np.errstate(divide='ignore'): #ignore zero-division error
    x = 1/x
x[x!=x] = 0 #convert inf and NaN's to 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing the array **in place** by using [`np.put()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.put.html):

```
In [56]: x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 5)

In [57]: x
Out[57]: array([-1. , -0.5,  0. ,  0.5,  1. ])

In [58]: indices = np.argwhere(x != 0)

In [59]: indices
Out[59]:
array([[0],
       [1],
       [3],
       [4]], dtype=int64)

In [60]: np.put(x, indices, 1/x[indices])

In [61]: x
Out[61]: array([-1., -2.,  0.,  2.,  1.])
```

The approach above does not create a new array, which could be very convenient if `x` is a large array.

Comment: Why are the last 2 values of your `x`, `[1., -1]`?  Shouldn't they be `[2., 1]`?

Comment: `np.put(x, indices, 1/x[indices])` is the correct function, not `putmask`.

Comment: @hpaulj: Thank you for spotting this bug. I fixed it by changing `1/x[indices]` to `1/x`. I tried `np.put(x, indices, 1/x[indices])` as you suggested but I got `array([ 2. , -1. ,  0. ,  0.5,  1. ])`.

Comment: `np.put` doesn't work with the boolean mask; it needs the indexes ([0,1,3,4]).

Comment: I just figured it out. Now the array `indices` passed to `np.put` is defined through `np.argwhere`. Thanks @hpaulj for catching this!